# Create an external hive metastore in a ec2 machine behind a load balancer

Tags: hive-metastore

I would like to create a external hive metastore service connected to mysql. How can I create a external hive metastore service on a EC2 machine providing api which can be connected to my EMR or Hdinsight or databricks cluster.

Lot of articles on using metastore service but cannot see any article on setting up hive metastore service on a ec2 machine